# is it possible to save animations so that you can drop them into the timeline later?

Tags: animation, rigging, shape-keys

I am currently working on my first ever proper animation, and am trying to get a hang of animation and rigging. I was wondering if it is possible to make an make an animation by keyframing an armature, and then save the animation, so that I can drop it into the timeline later. I don't know exactly when I want the animation to play, and most likely I want it to play multiple times, so being able to have it stored somewhere so that I can easily drop it into the timeline when I need it would be extremely useful. Something similar to shapekeys, with a slider I can pull to go through the animation would also work equally as well for me. Is this possible to achieve, and if so, how?

Comment: Have you looked into the NLA (Nonlinear Animation window) and how it works?

Comment: @moonboots I've never heard about that window before, but I will be sure to look into it now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can switch the dope sheet window to action editor, where you will then be able to save individual animations as *Actions*.

[image: switching to action editor in the dope sheet window]

Those actions can then be used, re-used and edited in the NLA editor, which was mentioned in a comment before.

Working with the NLA is certainly a learning curve and way too complex to go into here. I found [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hz1TwvSNsrA) very helpful in getting the hang of it.